# Get raw querystring of WebClient in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using a WebClient to make a POST request with a query string but I can't see the raw string. This is what I have:

```
WebClient TheWebClient = new WebClient();

TheWebClient.QueryString.Add("Param1", "1234");
TheWebClient.QueryString.Add("Param2", "4567");
TheWebClient.QueryString.Add("Param3", "4539");

var TheResponse = TheWebClient.UploadValues("https://www.example.com/posturl", "POST", TheWebClient.QueryString);

string TheResponseString = TheWebClient.Encoding.GetString(TheResponse);

//problem is that this only shows the keys
var RawQueryString = TheWebClient.QueryString;
```

How can I see the actual raw query string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[WebClient.UploadValues](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/900ted1f.aspx) doesn't save the request *"raw query string"* simply because you provided it with them, and it's not gonna change, thus is redundant.

Furthermore, **HttpPost requests** doesn't use query string for the request payload, it has a *url*, a message payload; which is appended after the headers, maybe *query string*. Thus there is nothing new the client class should let you know, so it won't save it.

Comment: Got it, got confused with a GET request.